# Magento 2.1: Assigning existing simple products to an existing configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, simple-product

I've imported a whole load of products into Magento, and as required they are set as configurable or simple.

All I need to do now is tie the simple products to their configurable "parent". I have the array mapped out, so it's not a matter of logic but rather how I actually achieve this.

I tried inserting a bunch of rows into "catalog_product_super_link" and that did work, temporarily. However, as soon as you save a product, the rows disappear from the database.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I've found a few solutions through Google that don't work, I'm not sure if something has changed between 2.0 and 2.1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing using CSV then you need to add one column named `configuration_variations` 
and add value in it with | separation.

ex.

```
configuration_variations
sku=AB1|sku=AB2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not using CSV, the data is coming from a bunch of JSON files that we've assembled by scraping an old 1990s HTML website.

Comment: Well, I bit the bullet and changed the way I approach the import by generating a simple CSV file (and then tacking on other fields programmatically in a second pass) and your approach works.

Comment: It should be noted though that the column header is actually "configurable_variations"

Comment: @Ronak in this case do we need to keep configurable_variations, configurable_variation_labels columns. If would be a great help if you provide a sample CSV?